# MongoDB with Node.JS: $where clause performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm not using mongoose but the official MongoDB driver for Node.js since it doesnt enforce defining an schema.

I read on the official documentation that with the $where clause you can make queries using JavaScript functions for increased flexibility, which I kinda need for some rather complex queries, but how exactly does it affect performance? Has any of you tried it out? I'm worried about it being a problem with a collection of 100,000 to 200,000 documents deployed on the Mongolab sandbox

The real question is, will it actually become a problem for a website's response time?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right to be concerned as `$where` is the query operator of last resort and should only be used if your query cannot be expressed using other operators.

From [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/):

> - `$where` evaluates JavaScript and cannot take advantage of indexes.    Therefore, query performance improves when you express your query
>     using the standard MongoDB operators (e.g., `$gt`, `$in`).
> - In general, you should use $where only when you can’t express your query    using another operator. If you must use `$where`, try to
>     include at least one other standard query operator to filter the
>     result set.    Using `$where` alone requires a table scan.

So yes, it's very likely that `$where` query performance will be inadequate in your situation. It's best to design your schema so that your required queries can all be performed without the need for `$where`.

Comment: I've read the docs too, thats why I was concerned, I just wanted to know if someone tried it out and found an actual significant difference. I figured a way to do it with MongoDB operators anyway :) Approving your answer since you were the only one to help, so that anyone searching this can see the quote and link to the docs

Comment: @CyborgFish It's definitely slower, but how much slower depends on the specifics of your query. Just try it yourself using your own queries to see the difference in your case.